# How to retrieve wordpress posts that published after last week?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

How to retrieve wordpress posts that published after last week or last month? I want a sql query.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)

Where wp_posts is the table that contains the posts and MONTH may be MONTH, DAY, WEEK, etc.